# CodeIgniter Login System not working 404 error bad request

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, http-status-code-404, bad-request

Using CodeIgniter to build a simple log in system.

I am getting this error when I try to submit my form data

**404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.**

I've no idea why! This is my form:

```
     <?php echo form_open('VerifyLogin/index'); ?>
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/></form>
```

This is the form action ->

```
 http://localhost/LoginTut/index.php/VerifyLogin/index
```

The user should be brought to a new page. I don't know why this issue is happening!! Any ideas?

Comment: First try to lower the Controller's name to verifylogin (same goes for the filename). Second; there is no need to refer to "index", as it's the default method that the Controller calls. Third; aren't you missing a localhost port or are you running port 80 (very dangerous ;))? You might also have forced Routes that break this URL. The same goes for the standard path you have set in the config.php file (/application/config/config.php)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, i would suggest a `Session` controller, this should handle login, logout etc. Maybe have a review of a [NetTuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/) series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at your other post and noticed that you named your controller "verify_login.php" but your class is named "VerifyLogin". In Codeigniter your class needs to be named the same as your file, just with capital letters. In order for that page to work correctly you should either rename your controller file to "verifyLogin.php" or rename your class to "Verify_Login".